# Ruby on Rails checking object before instantiate it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models **X** and **Y**, **X** has many **Y**, **Y** belongs to **X**.

At **Y** controller i need to add a method that constrain the ability of **X** to see or edit any other **Y** but it's related one.

Lets say i created an object **x1** that connected 3 different **Y**
and **x2** that connected to 4 other different **Y**
at show page if i call any y by id i'll get it regardless `session[x.id]` is
i need to compare `x.id` with `y.x_id`

if they are equal return true
the problem that i need to do that before instantiate the y object 
i don't want to use any gems 
if any one can help i'll deeply appreciate it.

thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def show
  @y = Y.find(params[:id])

  unless @y.x.id == session(x.id)
    render status: :forbidden, text: 'You are not allowed here!' and return
  end
end
```

Comment: Happy to know it helped.Please upvote it then, as some one has downvoted it

Comment: tried but > 15 reputation can`t vote
can i ask you something?
when i try to check integrity by passing a 'nil' x.id in view it gives me an error
so i tried to fix that by making before_action for X.exists? over and over but no luck

Comment: x which belongs to session....or the x which belongs to y ??? Better add the code snippet

Comment: that was wrong question sorry
i meant 
y.id => nil raise an error
beside i don`t know yet how to add code in comment

Comment: Add an if condition in first line checking if the value is present, then only make a Y.find statement. Dude, these small things you should figure out on your own, then only you will start to learn actually. I can spoon-feed but that won't help, you will get locked somewhere else again.

Comment: i did that
it didn`t work
it refer to the defionition of y each time

Answer (score 0):

> at show page if i call any y by id ill get it regardless, `session[x_id]`

It's up to you, what you show. You could restrict your y's simply with:

```
@y = X.find(session[:x_id]).ys.where(id: params[:id]).first 
# or faster
@y = Y.where(id: params[:id], x_id: (session[:x_id] || -1)).first # (session[:x_id] || -1) to prevent finding a record where x_id is null
```

Comment: Thank you for that